# Sendbird with React Native doesn’t work at all

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, sendbird

**[Problem/Question]**

Sendbird with React Native doesn't work at all

---

**[UIKit Version]**
`^3.4.2`

**[Reproduction Steps]**
I tried locally the following step-by-step Sendbird with React Native tutorial:
https://sendbird.com/docs/chat/uikit/v3/react-native/introduction/send-first-message

1st result (when running `npx pod-install`):

```
[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

pod install --repo-update --ansi exited with non-zero code: 1
```

So I added the `use_modular_headers!` on the top of my Podfile, and then:

2nd result:

```
ERROR  Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "ChatApp" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

I get the same errors when trying the `sendbird-uikit-react-native` sample repo:
Same issue when trying the sample:

- https://github.com/sendbird/sendbird-uikit-react-native/tree/main/sample

I tried different react-native versions, downgrading all packages, different Android SDK versions, Node.js versions, and code implementations - nothing works in React Native for me.

When I remove the `<SendbirdUIKitContainer appId={'APP_ID'} />...` wrapper the app works fine, no errors (obviously without any Sendbird integration).

Am I the only one that can't get the doc tutorial working?